# Do any birth photography books exist?

Tags: books, baby-photos

I am looking for a text that focuses specifically on birth photography. I have not yet been able to find any such example. If an entire book on the subject is not available I would also be interested in a text that has at least a large section of it's contents dedicated to this type of photography.

By birth photography I mean the documentation of the birth in a hospital or home environment from the babies first breaths to the parents first interactions. I have found plenty of texts that describe "Newborn Photography" which usually occurs from days 3-14 of the babies life and beyond.

Comment: Have you tried googling ["photographing childbirth"](https://www.google.com/search?q=photographing+childbirth&oq=photographing+childbirth)?

Comment: http://www.blurb.com/b/2631488-the-birth-photographer-s-handbook

Comment: @inkista Looks like you've found the answer (Technically, "Yes"). You should post it as an answer.

Comment: Done. :) I was a bit hesitant, since it looks like a self-published book.

Comment: i gotta say brave mom to put makeup while her contractions are going :)

Comment: I don't think you can find something like this unless the father is the photographer, i've been blessed 2 weeks ago and got a baby boy and i gotta tell you that it's extremely hard to get good photos in the first week, most of the time my son will be sleepy which is good to photograph him but to get to get a good shot i've to spend like 3 hours between crying, mom feeding, trying to get him to sleep, pose him (which will wake him up sometimes) and  repeat again. you have to be patient

Answer (score 2):

I think this may be too specialized a topic to have entire major-publisher books dedicated to it. Hate to sound all LMGTFY, but as I said in my earlier comment, just [googling on "photographing childbirth"](https://www.google.com/search?q=photographing%20childbirth&oq=photographing%20childbirth) produces a great many links, [FAQs](http://www.michellegareyphotography.com/2013/09/08/faq-for-photographers/), professional birth photographer websites, etc., and is how I found the following self-published book on Blurb:

[*The Birth Photographer's Handbook*](http://blurb.com/b/2631488-the-birth-photographer-s-handbook)

From the "About this book":

> This handbook is designed for aspiring and professional photographers
>   wanting to learn more about birth photography....

Would **not** suggest googling or Amazon-searching on "birth photography", since there are apparently a LOT of books with "The birth of photography" in the title/description. :D

Comment: Yes I have done a great deal of googling on the subject as well. Unfortunately those results as well as the FAQ you have linked to are either extremely light on content(blogs that try to sell services) or are focused on the business itself(which I am not interested in).

Comment: As for the "handbook", once I got past the excessive cost they are asking for it, I previewed 19 pages and was lets just say, unimpressed. At any rate thank you for your answer and assistance. Unfortunately I think it is a difficult topic to google and not get mixed results as you pointed out, and it also seems to be a topic not very well covered in general.

Comment: Yeah. This is why I was staying in the comments. Self-published books tend to be...variable in quality of content. And yes, that FAQ is about turning pro, but also mentions working in low light and confined spaces and being ready 24/7. That it's event photography. These are good facts to start to imagine your way into the mindset needed if you're coming from ground zero, and examples on the pro sites can start you thinking about composition ideas.

Comment: I have to agree with you. I think all I will have to work with is the bits and pieces from these websites(along with other non birth photography related knowledge and texts). Thanks for the help.

Comment: Maybe it's up to you to *write* the book. :) There's clearly a lack of competition!

Comment: I awarded this answer the bounty as I appreciate the effort. I did not select this answer as no actual text seems to exist beyond a self published book that I dont think anyone would actually buy since it is mostly fluff.